# Filtrar registros por Mês/Ano Codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

Tenho a seguinte estrutura SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `noticia` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_categoria` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `previa` text NOT NULL,
  `descricao` text,
  `imagem` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `data` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `views` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `youtube` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ativo` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`ativo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Gostaria de elaborar um SQL que faça a consulta dos registros, agrupando mês e ano. que apareça da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

1. Como eu posso agrupar MÊS/ANO para montar esta listagem?
   Para exibir, eu desenvolvo normal, minha dúvida é somente no SQL.

Pensei em fazer:

```
SELECT * FROM noticia GROUP BY MONTH(data);
```

Se eu fizer desta forma, agrupará somente por mês, e se tiver no próximo ano o mesmo mês, agrupará também.. E não é essa intenção. Agradeço!

Comment: Está usando mysql? Existe uma forma melhor pra se fazer isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui encontrar uma solução. Se caso alguém precisar, está ai.

```
SELECT 
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data) AS mes, 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM data) AS ano, 
    COUNT(id) AS total_noticia, 
    (CASE month(data) 
        when 1 then 'Janeiro'
        when 2 then 'Fevereiro'
        when 3 then 'Março'
        when 4 then 'Abril'
        when 5 then 'Maio'
        when 6 then 'Junho'
        when 7 then 'Julho'
        when 8 then 'Agosto'
        when 9 then 'Setembro'
        when 10 then 'Outubro'
        when 11 then 'Novembro'
        when 12 then 'Dezembro'
    END) AS mes_extenso
FROM 
    noticia 
GROUP BY 
    mes
```